# How to pull all available query fields for an SOQL object?

Tags: salesforce

So, I'm seeing Stackoverflow is more responsive than the actual Salesforce community and I'm reposting my question from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=APIs_and_Integration&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=9060G0000005atXQAQ):

How can I pull a list of all of the available query fields for an SOQL object? I have my DataLoader script ready to go, but I need a way to pull all the query fields for specific SOQL data objects and feed them into my process-conf.xml file in DataLoader to pull the values of all those fields to a separate location. I have the DataLoader value pulling already setup, but I need a way to get all the available query fields as they continue to change. The ANT Migration Tool does not appear to be able to pull the query fields itself.

ANT Tool configuration:

```
# build.properties  
# Specify the login credentials for the desired Salesforce organization
sf.username = <test user acct>
sf.password = <password>
#sf.sessionId = <Insert your Salesforce session id here.  Use this or username/password above.  Cannot use both>
#sf.pkgName = <Insert comma separated package names to be retrieved>
#sf.zipFile = <Insert path of the zipfile to be retrieved>
#sf.metadataType = <Insert metadata type name for which listMetadata or bulkRetrieve operations are to be performed>   
sf.serverurl = https://na3.salesforce.com
sf.maxPoll = 20
# If your network requires an HTTP proxy, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html for configuration.
#
logType=Detail
```

build.xml

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">

    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>

    <!-- Setting default value for username, password and session id properties to empty string 
         so unset values are treated as empty. Without this, ant expressions such as ${sf.username}
         will be treated literally.
    -->
    <condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="ant-salesforce.jar" />           
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!-- See what happens here -->
    <target name="retrieveSOQL">
      <sf:retrieve 
          username="${sf.username}" 
          password="${sf.password}" 
          sessionId="${sf.sessionId}"
          serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" 
          retrieveTarget="output" 
          unpackaged="package.xml"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>Project__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

process-conf.xml

```
<beans>
    <bean id="AccountExtract"
          class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
          singleton="false">
      <description>csvAccountExtract job</description>
        <property name="name" value="csvAccountExtract"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="C:\Users\user\Desktop\salesforce_backup\sfdcSoapTrace.log"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://na3.salesforce.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="<username>"/>
                <!-- password below has been encrypted using key file, therefore it will not work without the key setting: process.encryptionKeyFile
                the password is not a valid encrypted value, please generate the real value using encrypt.bat utility -->
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="<password>"/>
                <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="key.txt"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="200"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select Id, IsDeleted, MasterRecordId, Name, Type, RecordTypeId, ParentId, BillingStreet FROM Account"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Users\user\Desktop\account.csv"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
...
</beans>
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about your configuration of DataLoader and Ant? Looks like you need to write custom script which pull names of fields from required Salesforce Objects via REST or SOAP API before your Ant job.

Comment: Gleb, could you be more specific in what you're asking? Do you want to see config files in how I set up ANT since that's where the potential problem lies? Dataloader has a simple batch script that pulls the SOQL table values from the query fields that the ANT Migration Tool pulls from Salesforce and I think the issue resides around not all the needed fields are getting pulled from ANT.

Comment: Yes, I told about Ant configs which you using. It will help other users to clearly understand your case and quicker help you. Possibly this discussion can help you - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MUGSQA4

Comment: Thanks Gleb. That's right on topic. It appears their solution did some work with the build.xml file because after running the ANT Migration Tool, it downloads tables in XML files and I parsed that output through a Powershell script to pull the relevant fields. The missing fields that I'd see in Dataloader WebUI don't come up in the downloaded XML files that get parsed.